# How to show userdata from tank_auth in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication, tankauth

What is the right way to get all the data from the 'users' table in my database, using Tank Auth?

I tried it with just with `$this->db->get('users');`

But how do i get the data for the specific logged-in user?
Do I have to use `$this->tank_auth->get_user_id();`?

Here's what I've tried:

```
function get_user_data()
{
    $id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $users = $this->db->get('users');

    return $users->result();
}
```

I hope somebody can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will get data about the current logged user.

In your controller:

```
$this->load->library('tank_auth');

if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
    exit('no logged user');
} else {
    $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    $user_data = $this->users->get_user_by_id($user_id,1);
}
```

Comment: why do i get the error: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 2 for Users::get_user_by_id(), called in /var/www/vhosts/een-site-bouwen.nl/subdomains/kees/httpdocs/application/controllers/members.php on line 20 and defined
Filename: tank_auth/users.php
Line Number: 34

Comment: so how do i call the data in the views?

Comment: $this->load->view('your_view.php', array('user_data' => $user_data));

Comment: I think it will help you if you look for tutorials of codeigniter basis.

Comment: i know how to do it like $data['user_data'] but i forgot how to do it with just $user_data or something.

Comment: $this->load->vars('user_data', $user_data); http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: oh yeah. sorry for the dumb question. i'll accept your answer :)